# Why can't I use a varchar column as an X-Axis in Snowflake Dashboard?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column defined as TO_VARCHAR(START_TIME, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh')

I would like to use this column as an X-Axis in a Snowsight dashboard but it won't let me do that...
Any particular reason I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're trying to build a line chart. Unlike numbers or dates, a varchar field can't be described as strictly increasing or decreasing, which is why I believe SF is picky about data type for the **X-Axis**.

[image]

I suggest you go for a **Bar Chart** instead

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work, as the X axis can't be an arbitrary string in a line chart:

```sql
with data(t, d) as (
    select * from values('2020-10-10 03:03:01', 1), ('2020-10-11 05:03:01', 2), ('2020-10-13 08:03:01', 6)
)

select TO_VARCHAR(t::timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh') ts, d
from data
```

[image]

Instead, use a fully formatted timestamp - even as a string:

```sql
with data(t, d) as (
    select * from values('2020-10-10 03:03:01', 1), ('2020-10-11 05:03:01', 2), ('2020-10-13 08:03:01', 6)
)

select TO_VARCHAR(t::timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') ts, d
from data
```

[image]